# Do Spanish surgeons shout “¡Al ataque!” before they begin an operation?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, español-neutral

En inglés: I was recently reading a Spanish book for children which had various suggestions for role playing ideas and one was some sort of mock surgical procedure.  Not much dialog was suggested, but what surprised me was that the book suggested role players shout out “¡Al ataque!” before starting the surgery.  The book then went on with instructions to direct the children to start tickling the patient. 
 Is it realistic for a surgeon in a Spanish speaking country to begin an operation with this phrase?

En español: Hace poco tiempo estuve leyendo un libro español para niños que tenía diversas sugerencias para juegos de roles y una de ellas era la cirugía.  Poco diálogo se propuso, pero lo que me sorprendió era que el libro sugirió que los jugadores griten «¡Al ataque!» antes de comenzar la cirugía.  El libro luego continuó con instrucciones dirigiendo a los niños a hacerle cosquillas al paciente, pero me hizo pensar si cirujanos usan una palabra o frase especial antes de comenzar la cirugía.  ¿Es realista que un cirujano en un país hispanoparlante utilice esta frase para comenzar una operación?

Comment: @walen si no he entendido mal la pregunta, creo que lo que Lisa quiere saber es si hay alguna frase estándar en español que los cirujanos usen al inicio de las intervenciones quirúrgicas, dado que decir "¡al ataque!" le parece obviamente fuera de lugar. No creo que sea una pregunta _off-topic_.

Comment: @walen sí, pero si te fijas, también dice _"Is this really what surgeons say in an operating room?"_ además de (como tú también apuntas) _"if real surgeons [...] use something different, let us know"_, lo que me hace pensar que igual lo que está buscando no es una traducción de "al ataque" sino una alternativa más realista.

Comment: @LisaBeck A softer way of saying that in Spanish would be: *¡Manos a la obra!* *Al ataque* sounds rather aggressive or even funny, and can be used for example by people who are about to start eating a well-served meal.

Comment: "Hands on!"
"On charge!"
No, los cirujanos no suelen decir eso. Más lógico sería: "comencemos", "adelante", "manos a la obra".

Comment: @Charlie Gracias por tus comentarios. Tienes buena comprensión de lo que estaba tratando de preguntar. El hecho que encontré esta frase en un libro para niños es simplemente añadido como antecedente para ayudar a otros a entender la razón por la pregunta. Aunque me gusta la respuesta de Gustavson, en verdad sólo quiero saber qué, si hay algo, los cirujanos dicen antes de operar ... algo oficial o algo dicen habitualmente. La pregunta es un poco inusual para mí porque normalmente, sé la palabra o frase en inglés, pero esta vez, no. Había esperado que alguien sabría.

Comment: Mientras tanto, parece que la respuesta de @Billeeb funcionaría.  Pero si hay una persona leyendo esto quién conoce a un cirujano (o es cirujano), quizás esa persona podría hacer la pregunta.  También, si miras mucho de _ER_ o _Código Negro_ y sabes de un episodio dónde los cirujanos dicen algo específico antes de operar, por favor, compartirlo con nosotros.  No me importa si sólo tienes el inglés o sólo tienes el español.  La comunidad puede resolverlo con sólo una parte de la ecuación.

Comment: No, no hay ninguna frase "especial" que sea "típica" de cirujanos cuando comienzan una operación. Nada es como ER o House. Así que quédate con cualquiera de esas frases pues son las que darían inicio a cualquier cosa.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't fit this site and doesn't include a link to the source. // Maybe you could get confirmation of what @Billeeb said over at Health SE.

Comment: @aparente001 If you feel you need to vote to close this for OT reasons, you have every right to do so, but, just so you know, I'm in the process of finding out what surgeons say in the U.S. I'll think about Health SE, but haven't gotten the impression a lot of surgeons are using it. I'm going to see if a couple of other sources can get me a solid answer. It kind of depends on what I find, but if it's worthwhile, I could answer my own question. If need be I could even edit the Q. & make any necessary revisions to the post. I'll return to this thread & post a comment regardless of what is found.

Comment: @aparente001 Well, I can't say the results I've received thus far are what anyone would call "earth shattering," but I think I'll be able to cobble together enough from subject matter experts to at least provide some words/phrases on the English side. I'm not crazy about giving them a straight translation, however, since Spanish-speaking surgeons might not use the same words/phrases, so I'll need some time to hunt those down, too (unless some knowledgeable person steps forward and blows us away w/one of those well-researched thorough posts based on first hand experience or terrific resources).

Comment: @LisaBeck - How about a link to the source?  Or if it's not on the web, the title and author, along with the context from the story?

Comment: @aparente001  To be perfectly honest, I don't think the actual 100 some odd words of instruction for this role-playing suggestion in this book I refer to really advances understanding anymore than what I've already given.  And, oddly enough, the same search method that led me to the book before, no longer brings that book up in the search results.  I may have the link to it in another location.  If I find it, I'll share it with you simply because you seem interested, but to emphasize, I don't think details beyond what I've already included are of any significance.

Comment: @LisaBeck - What I want to check is the tone, to see whether the reader should take "¡Al ataque!" literally, or whether this was just a dramatic added touch (which is what I suspect).  The Spanish version of "Big dog, little dog," has a similar phrase, "¡Al hotel!"

Comment: @aparente001  Oh, that's what you were getting at.  Yeah, I definitely believe it was a real abstraction from the type of communication actual surgeons would have.  I mean, who would yell that out before starting an operation?  Hannibal Lecter?  Dr. Mengele?  I hadn't thought much about how I would revise the question while keeping the impetus for my asking it intact, but I can omit that from the question without having to change too much of the rest.  I was hoping to get more feedback on the Spanish side of things before making revisions and adding my answer.

Comment: Lisa, I tried to reformulate your question so that the @walen  comment about colloquial use of "¡Al ataque!" would fit as an answer.  If you don't like my edit, please edit further or roll back. // My hunch about the book you read is that the author was having fun, but that real surgeons don't begin operations with a fanfare.  Perhaps in a particularly emotionally charged operation the lead surgeon might say something inspirational but I imagine it would be something personal rather than formulaic.

Comment: I think we would do well to remember that this is taken from a role play for children. Note for instance that they are not given a scalpel to make an incision but they tickle the simulated patient instead. So there is no particular reason to suppose that what they shout is realistic either.

Comment: @walen why not make your comments about colloquial use into an answer to complement that of Charlie?

Comment: I think the fact that it's a mock surgical procedure, a game for children, is relevant here.  The phrase "al ataque" might seem flippant enough so that a real surgeon would tend to avoid it. The scalpel is not a weapon, but the phrase suggests a military operation.

Comment: @aparente001  When I first saw your edit, my first reaction was somewhat more of a "What did you do to my question?!"  Then I read all the comments and then I read your edited version again.  It's good.  Real good.  Thank you.  As for the research some suggested I should have done before posting the question, all I can say is better late than later.  I'll incorporate my scant findings in some sort of answer I'll cobble together.  Some might find it as OT as the question initially posted, but don't worry ... I won't give myself the coveted green checkmark.

Comment: @LisaBeck - Oh, but giving your own answer the checkmark is a sign that you've really gotten the hang of SE!  Don't hesitate to do so if your response provides the best answer.  // Also -- for future reference: if it's your question, and you want to roll back an edit completely or partially, it's your right to do so (except at Parenting Beta Stack Exchange, where the moderators run the site like a military junta).

Comment: @aparente001 Your last comment made me laugh out loud, especially after a recent experience with the English Language & Usage SE.  It turned out well, but the initial process had me thinking, "Are you guys for real?"  I suppose some topics such as parenting and the English language tend to attract certain personality types.

Comment: @aparente001  BTW, I decided to make one small change to your edit.  As good as it was, I wasn't crazy about the title.  I just wanted to try to generate more interest for this discussion thread to anyone who might stumble upon it.  If someone wants to accuse me of making it more "clickbaity" (is that a word?), I'll take the hit.

Comment: @LisaBeck - Very nice title.  And anything eye-catching helps promote the site.

Comment: En una operación con el paciente despierto (anestesia tópica, local, epidural, etc) debe asustar oir al cirujano gritar "**Al ataque**" !!

Comment: I can't believe nobody has proposed the sentence "Al tajo".

Comment: @FGSUZ  "Al tajo" as in "[**down to business**](https://context.reverso.net/translation/spanish-english/al+tajo#down+to+business)"?  Interesting.  I can see a surgeon announcing that before an operation.  Thank you for suggesting it.  It's a phrase I had not heard before.

Comment: @FGSUZ and Lisa - Here's another one: *Manos a la obra*, which means "Let's get going."

Comment: @aparente001 Another excellent phrase to start incorporating into my speech!  Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como [explica Charlie](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23766/5481), no es realista que un cirujano haga una "llamada a las armas" cuando está a punto de ayudar a una persona mediante un tratamiento médico.

Creo que el matiz se debe a lo siguiente: "Al ataque" puede ser usado como una exhortación o frase de aliento, a la par que de declaración de intenciones ("Voy a por ti"). Podría entenderse como otra forma de decir "ánimo" cuando vas a empezar una tarea, pero de forma más agresiva. Podrías decir "Al ataque" o "A la carga" tras poner un plato de guisantes (o helado) delante de tus hijos, y lo que harías sería animarles a comenzar la acción (de comer) con brío.

Explicas que esto es **un juego de rol** y la cirugía consiste en **hacer cosquillas**. Posiblemente los traductores (o incluso los creadores del juego) obviaron la parte del "tratamiento médico" y se centraron en un "ataque mediante cosquillas (aunque llamado "*cirugía*")" al otro jugador. De ahí que elijan una frase tan poco apropiada para el rol del médico. Están pensando solo en la acción de asaltar a alguien y hacerle cosquillas, y no en el rol de los jugadores.

Otras frases que podrían haber usado para declarar que empiezan con la tarea podrían haber sido

- Manos a la obra
- Vamos por partes (que tiene un cierto doble sentido cuando la pronuncia un cirujano...)
- Empecemos con tu "tratamiento"

Pero, de nuevo, supongo que por la naturaleza del juego eligieron "Al ataque" para poner a los jugadores más en situación frente al "asalto mediante cosquillas" que se va a producir.

Comment: +1. // ¿Qué es "Voy a por ti"?  Sólo conozco "Voy por ti" y "Ahí te voy".

Comment: You get the green checkmark simply because you not only seem to try to get into the mindset of the author who wrote the book, but you also add some good suggestions for what a surgeon might really say before an operation.  So, for addressing both those points, and so succinctly, too, it goes to you.

Answer (score 5):

No, no es realista. La expresión "¡Al ataque!" yo diría que se usa más en combates, cuando unos cargan contra otros, y ni siquiera en esos ámbitos es realista, se usa más en obras literarias e incluso con un cierto tono desenfadado:

> *DIOMEDES: ¡Soldados!*
>
> *(Movilización general.)*
>
> *DIOMEDES: ¡Oficial, disponga doce artesanos de mar a las órdenes de
>   Aquiles! ¡Preparen la ofensiva!*
>
> *OFICIAL: ¡Al ataque!*
>
> *(Tambores y trompetas.)*
>
> *DIOMEDES: ¡Que no huya ninguna!*
>
> Luis de Tavira, "La pasión de Pentesilea", 1991 (México).

Y no te creas que he encontrado muchos casos en el CREA y muchos menos en el CORDE. Por otro lado, buscando una alternativa he preguntado a un par de familiares míos que son médicos (mas no cirujanos), y me han dicho que no tienen constancia de que haya alguna frase estándar que decir en esas situaciones.

Comment: Well done effort and interesting, too.  Plus, after aparente001's talk of voting to close this question off, you have no idea how grateful I was to see that someone had populated this thread with an answer.  I secretly hoped that it would buy me some time to collect the information I needed to be able to offer an answer of my own.  Mil gracias.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a surgeon and I do not know any (only a couple of ER nurses), so I cannot answer whether surgeons specifically do or do not use *"¡Al ataque!"* before an intervention. But I can tell you how *"¡Al ataque!"* is used *in general*.

*"¡Al ataque!"* in Spain can be (and is) used colloquially in any situation where a goal-oriented task is to be done:

- a soccer team before entering the field;
- a teacher to let their students know they can begin answering the test;
- a hungry pal about to eat a delicious meal;
- and yes, even a surgeon before confronting whichever malicious thing exists in your body that needs to be fixed.

I don't think any Spanish patient would find *"¡Al ataque!"* offensive or inappropriate; however, sensitivity towards this kind of matters in the US is waaaay higher (in my experience), hence my initial suggestion of translating it as a milder "Forward!" when needed.

Answer (score 0):

I scoured the web for sites and forums that might put me in touch with real live surgeons in an attempt to answer this question.  I don't know that I succeeded too well in that, but then again, I don't know how many surgeons would spend their valuable time in a forum open to the general public, so when those efforts dried up rather quickly, I did not attempt to pursue fresher vines of knowledge.  Instead, I'll leave you with some comments I was able to collect over on [**Quora**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora) (which is my first go-to site when I have a question that isn't fitting in neatly with the categories here at StackExchange).  For those of you who haven't heard, Quora has both an English version and a Spanish one.  I posted my question on both and these are some of the answers:

### **English Quora:**

**Multiple mentions:**
"Time Out"
"Knife"

**Other mentions:**
"It's showtime."
"Once more unto the breach, dear friends, once more."
"Let's do this!"

### **Spanish Quora**

Well, let's just say that I have nothing yet to add here.  The one response just isn't specific enough to add here and the other, well, the other is a question with a twist of humor.  If you'd like to see the English answers in full context, visit this link:

[**Is there a special word or phrase surgeons say (officially or habitually) before operating on a patient?**](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-special-word-or-phrase-surgeons-say-officially-or-habitually-before-operating-on-a-patient)

For the Spanish, visit this one:

[**¿Hay una palabra o frase específica que dicen (oficialmente o habitualmente) los cirujanos en países donde se habla español antes de operar a un paciente?**](https://es.quora.com/Hay-una-palabra-o-frase-espec%C3%ADfica-que-dicen-oficialmente-o-habitualmente-los-cirujanos-en-pa%C3%ADses-donde-se-habla-espa%C3%B1ol-antes-de-operar-a-un-paciente)

Because I feel as if my attempt to research this falls just a little bit short and isn't quite as informative as it could be, I wanted to also leave you with something else I came across in the process.  It is a chart from the World Health Organization.  More specifically, it is a surgery checklist written in several different languages to include English and Spanish.  I don't know how useful these images are to you, but I include them with the hope that you find them interesting.

[image]

[image]

I think what I may have been thinking about when I first saw the phrase “¡Al ataque!” were the types of scenes you see in the following clips:

https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/b5b63a34-a71f-4d7d-97b4-6a699df8392f
https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/074d6c1d-a0a0-4e01-86a6-a79fb168f9cc
https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/f76e6fc3-f41c-4f45-9cdd-f2dada38ec33

The clip below made me wonder if it might have influenced the author to some degree:

https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/9ce7d414-6a1d-4cef-9384-219a458dc4e9

Though it is a bit of a stretch to think that the author might have been influenced by the scene above, *The Lorax* did do very well at the box office and it *was* dubbed into Spanish.  But I don't know when the book was published, so I can’t say which came first — the book I’ve referred to in this post or *El Lórax*.  More likely, however, and as Diego has mentioned, “¡Al ataque!” is just a good way to generate enthusiasm for an operation, especially a tickling operation.  Though Diego’s other suggestions for what a surgeon might say work just as well in my opinion, I don’t think any of them quite generate a sentiment of “comenzar con brio” quite like “¡Al ataque!” does.

As for confusing the use of a defibrillator with a surgical operation, I suppose that’s a reasonable thing for a person without a medical background to do.  And perhaps it may be why “¡Al ataque!” didn’t seem entirely out of place to me initially.  After all, when you take two paddles and deliver an electric shock with them to a person’s chest, I guess you could call that an attack ... an attack to the heart!  Seriously though, protocol in such situations doesn’t advise shouting out “Attack!”  Instead, you want to clear the area for all the appropriate reasons, but mainly because you want everyone but the victim to stand clear of the electricity and because touching the victim is potentially fatal.  According to one source, you are to say:

> **I'm Clear, you're clear, we're all clear" while ensuring that the operator is not touching the victim or standing in a wet environment next to the victim that could conduct electricity through the rescuer.**
>
> — From [***First Aid/Automated External Defibrillation (AED)***](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/First_Aid/Automated_External_Defibrillation)

Though this Wikibook has been translated into Spanish, it isn’t a word for word translation, and no mention is made of what should be said to other first responders or bystanders, but I would imagine it is some form of “¡Claro!” and not “Al ataque!”

---

As an educational sidenote, if you should ever need a defibrillator, and you’re in a Spanish-speaking country, you want to look for a **DESA** which is the Spanish equivalent of an AED and stands for **desfibrilador externo semiautomático.**  If signs for it don’t have that acronym on them, they might look like this:

[image]

You might want to get some training before you ever have to use one, though.

Comment: @walen Well, in my defense, the phrase "Al ataque!" is, the last time I checked, a Spanish phrase and it was found in a book written in Spanish.  Speculation about why the author chose to use that Spanish phrase sounds to me like it's a question about the Spanish language.  As for the rest, I was hoping to get more of a response to my question about what surgeons say before an operation in general, but also _in the Spanish language._

Comment: @walen Plus, how many visiting this thread will learn something they didn't know before about _the Spanish language?_  My guess is quite a few ... even if the only answer they read is mine (if only for the fact that it is written in English).

Comment: @LisaBeck: me pierdo en tu razonamiento: algunos hemos aprendido algo sobre el español porque tu respuesta está escrita en inglés (¿?)